# Proof that helical segments correspond to right triangles "wrapped" around the helix's cylinder?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

Consider a helical segment that starts at the base of a cylinder and makes it no more than once of the way around the cylinder.

It strikes me as obvious (for whatever that's worth) that the length of this segment "corresponds to a 'wrapped' right triangle"; that is, that the length of this segment equals the length of the hypotenuse of a right triangle with legs a and b such that a's length is the length of a line segment running from the end of the helical segment along the cylinder back to the base of the cylinder, and b's length is the length from there around the base back to the starting point of the helical segment.

I expect there to be a well-known proof/theorem of this, but all I've found so far is people assuming it in making other points and others showing it or something like it with pictures/videos. Can anyone please direct me to or show me the actual mathematical proof/theorem?

Comment: Well you can use parametric equation and find explicitly the path length. Not very difficult either.

Comment: I think you can use the fact that the intrinsic metric on the cylinder is flat hence you can translate the problem isometrically to a rectangle in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ using a nice change of co-ordinates.  The helical segment will be mapped to a straight line (segment) in $\mathbb{R}^{2}.$